# Blazor onclick not working when not authenticated even if on AllowAnonymous page

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor

I have a blazor application (net6.0) that authenticates users using Microsoft Azure AD. This authentication is suppose to be optional. Unauthenticated users can still use the application but will have a more limited set of functionality.

To accomplish this, I used the net6.0 template for azure authentication and then modified the _Host.cshtml file to add the @attribute [AllowAnonymous]. For loading the page, this works fine. Regardless of if I am authenticated or not the page loads, and  components limit what is shown.

However, whenever I click a button while unauthenticated I just get a CORS error rather than the actual action being performed. If I am authenticated then it works perfectly fine. The button should work regardless of authentication status.

Given that it works authenticated but not unauthenticated, I am wondering if there is something more I need to configure to get this to work. I have included example code for App.razor, _Host.cshtml, and Index.razor.

My App.razor file

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">   
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <!--<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />-->
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

My _Host.cshtml (note the AllowAnonymous attribute)

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@namespace UnbcApp.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

And my Index.razor with a single button that should work regardless of authenticated or not.

```
@page "/"

<button @onclick="countup">Count is: @count</button>

@code {
    int count;
    private void countup() {
        count++;
    }
}
```

When authenticated clicking the button here simply increments the count and displays it on the button. However, when not authenticated I get the following set of errors in the console. (Some URL information is purposefully omitted here.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/*******' (redirected from 'https://localhost:7139/_blazor/initializers') from origin 'https://localhost:7139' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED login.microsoftonline.com/*********
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch 
    at blazor.server.js:1:126694
    at Gn (blazor.server.js:1:126852)
    at blazor.server.js:1:131402
    at blazor.server.js:1:131408
```

Comment: Enable the cors policy in the application by adding the `builder.Services.AddCors` in `Program.cs` file.

Comment: Refer this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1026379/access-to-fetch-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-react) once.

Comment: Even I got the same error,working on it.